# is there conversion function for color values between #FFFFFF <-> 0xFFFFFF

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

is there a conversion function for color values between "#FFFFFF" <-> 0xFFFFFF

I like to read a value from String and convert it to hex number

Comment: I don't know action script, but can't you just replace the "#" with "0x"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace # with either 0x or empty string and do a ParseInt("FFFFFF", 16)? Remember that #FFF is valid and equal to #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the flex compiler you can use the mx.styles.StyleManager to convert named colours (such as the format #xxxxxx or even common names like red) to a uint.

[API Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/styles/StyleManager.html#getColorName())